# Relations Between 3 models in rails (Teacher,Subject,Student)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help to structure the relations between 3 models in rails 
Teacher, Subject and Student

I don't know if it is possible, but I hope so

a students can be in multiple subjects, and he belong to a teacher

a subject can have multiple students and it belongs to a teacher

Teachers may be able to add subjects and to acces all students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to learn Ruby on Rails Associations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

There are:

1. has_many
2. has_one

Now in your particular case you need make your:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  belongs_to :teacher
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :subjects
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  has_many :subjects
end
```

You also need to create certain migrations

You migrations need to have references as well! http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

There is good rails g migration approach lets you add references to existing model:

```
$ bin/rails generate migration AddStudentRefToSubjects student:references
```

what returns:

```
class AddStudentRefToSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :subjects, :student, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Finally you can access your instances through (example)

```
Subject.last.students // returns all students for last subject in your DB
Teacher.last.students // returns all students for last teacher in your DB
Subject.last.teacher // returns teacher instance of last subject
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create relations that you want with just these three models. Since you have many to many relation between subject and student you need to create one more model, and create has many through association between student and subject, something like AttendingSubject and it should belong_to :student and belong_to :subject.

`class AttendingSubject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :subject
end`

Then for Student you need

`class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects, through: :attending_subjects
  belongs_to :teacher`

And for Subject

`class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subjects, through: :attending_subjects
  belongs_to :teacher
end`

And for Teacher

`class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :subjects
 has_many :students
end`

Here's more about has many through association.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association